# MongoDB - get data from table and check if id exists in another

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As my title say's, is it possible to query (with nodejs) a list of data in my mongodb, and check if the id exists in another table?

So lets say I have:

```
var users = new Schema({
name: String
});
```

And I have another table:

```
var books = new Schema({
user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }
});
```

When I get 'all' the users, I want to check if they have books for example. How would I go about this in nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with nested loops and record counting:

```
function getAllUsersWithBooks (callback) {
  var books_by_users = []

  // return only user_id
  user.find({}, {_id : 1}, function (e, ids) {
    if (e) return callback(e);

    var remaining = ids.length;

    ids.forEach(function (user) {
         books.find({user_id : user._id}, function (e, books) {
             if (e) return callback(e);

             var users_books = {user_id : user:_id, books : []};
             var books_left = books.length;

             books.forEach(function (b) {
                 users_books.books.push(b.toObject());
                 if (!--booksLeft) {
                    books_by_user.push(user_books);
                    if (!--remaining) {
                       callback(null, books_by_user);
                    }
                 }
             })
         })
    })
  })
}

getAllUsersWithBooks(function (e, list) {
    if (e) {
        // handle error
    }
    console.log(list);
    /*
      [{user_id : 123123, books : [b1, b2, etc],
       {user_id : 342342, books : [b3, b4, etc]}
     */
})
```

Comment: @DennisSmink: does this not work for you or did I mis-read your question? Thanks